# Weekly/Fortnightly Time Filter data structure

Tags: c#, sql

I want to set up a weekly/fortnightly time filter Such that things can only happen within certain times on certain days. I was wondering if there was a data convention out there for something like this. Currently the best i can come up with is something that represents start and end time for each 14 days in the fortnight but this cant handle the case when there are multiple times a day eg Monday 0900-1200 and Monday 1300-1500. I'm restricted to one time span per day.

example of what i have come up with so far

```
class schedule{
    MondayWeekOneStartTime;
    MondayWeekOneEndTime;
    TuesdayWeekOneStartTime;
    TuesdayWeekOneEndTime;
    ...
}
```

This Data Structure will be stored as a table(s) in an sql database so i want to keep the amount of columns to a minimum. Is there a better way to represent this type of schedule or am i stuck with this way?

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
class ScheduleDay
{

    DayOfWeek Day;
    Timespan[] Times   

}

class Schedule
{

    ScheduleDay[] Days;

}
```

And in your DB you create two tables, one for Schedule with id and (per example) name, and other for ScheduleDay with id, scheduleid, day, start, end.

In this way you can handle as many timespans as you want.